# differential equation12

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After 30 days of radioactive decay,100 mg of a radioactive substance was observed to remain. After 120 days, only 30 mg of this substance was left. 
A. How much substance was originally present?
B. What is the half-life of this radioactive substance?
C. How long will it take before only 1% of the original amount remains?

I have no clue what so ever

Comment: Radioactive material follows exponential decay.  This should be in one of the first few chapters of your DEs book, if I guess correctly.

Comment: Yes it is! It's in like chapter 2

Comment: So I would need to do dQ/dt=-kQ, with k>0?

Comment: That seems to be right.  The biggest trick to these problems is to make sure you don't forget your constants of integration... (FYI: I'm signing off for the night, so I won't respond after this, probably.)

Comment: @user1988: Please see update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will get you kicked off. As mentioned in the comments, we use an exponential for these types of problems, so we have:

$$A(t) = ce^{kt}$$

Now all you need to do is use the conditions specified in the problem to find the particular solution.

- Using $t = 30$ and $A(30) = 100$, we get: $\displaystyle 100 = ce^{30k}$.
- Using $t = 120$ and $A(120) = 30$, we get: $\displaystyle 30 = ce^{120k}$.

The resulting system of equations is:

$$100 = ce^{30k}$$
$$30 = ce^{120k}$$

Using the first equation, we get:

$$\displaystyle c = \frac{100}{e^{30k}} = 100e^{-30k}$$

Substituting into the second equation, you have: $30 = 100e^{-30k} e^{120k} = 100e^{90k}$, or, $\frac{30}{100} = e^{90k}$, so

$$\displaystyle \ln\left(\frac{30}{100}\right) = 90k \rightarrow k = -0.013377$$

Notice here that $k$ is in fact negative. This is what you would expect given that we are talking about decay rather than growth.

Using the equation for $c$, we have:

$$\displaystyle c = 100e^{-30 \times -0.013377} = 149.38$$

The amount $A$ as a function of time is given by:

$$\displaystyle A(t) = 149.38e^{-0.013377t}$$

To find the original amount of substance, use $t=0$, and we get:

$$A(0) = 149.38e^0 = 149.38~~ \text{mg}$$

How long will it take before only 1% of the "original amount remains"?

$$149.38 e^{-0.013377t} = .01 \times 149.38 \rightarrow t = 344.26 ~~ \text{days}.$$

Comment: I swear you are my savior and I did work it out, I did not quite get that answer. I used 10 instead of 90.

Comment: @user1988: But, you see why that is not correct - right?

Comment: Yes I do!So let me work this out and then I will see if I did this all correctly.

Comment: So for the second part would my e^(-kt)=.10 making it t=ln2/k?

Comment: which would bring me to (ln2)/.013377?

Comment: So then would we get 14.938?

Comment: Oh ok I see where I went wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: Good work, Amzoti! TGIF!!